# Is it possible to add nodes/edges to a graphDB via web library?

Tags: jquery, neo4j, visualization, graph-databases, graph-visualization

I'm trying to make a tool that will have a graph component. I wanted users to be able to build/model their own relationships. I was thinking of something similar to how mind map software works(users create nodes and edges,etc..).

I was hoping to use Neo4J(they have a library but I don't think you can add nodes/edges to it) but honestly any web library would work because I can transfer the data to their format, let users modify it then push the changes back to my backend DB.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most graphDBs offer a REST endpoint for CRUD operations: Neo4J offers [also a specific transactional one](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html) for ACID operations.

Basically you can use `CREATE` and `MATCH` queries to create or update/delete your data in the database, and send them by an AJAX call to the Neo4J server.

Using a [graph drawing library](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/) you can trigger, based on the user activity, the ajax requests and create the elements in the database.

Have a look [at the Cypher Cheatsheet](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1/cypher-refcard/) for an overview of the possible operations.

**Note**: probably you don't want to expose your database to the user completely, so I'd say maybe to wrap the REST interface with a Business Software layer of yours so that you can control all the process (and not distribuite the Authentication credentials to the user as well).